# Mapping table name with class in mvc

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

In my database, I have a table named `tblEmp`. Now I have created a class `Employee` in my model.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MvcDemo.Models
{
    [Table("tblEmp")]
    public class Employee
    {
        public int Eid { get; set; }
        public string   Name    { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public int Did { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have used `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;` and also added `System.Data.Entity`, but it is still showing:

> Type or namespace name "table could not be found"

Comment: which version of entity framework you are using? in EF 5 it has changed to using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema; Also I am assuming that you correctly installed the entity framework from nuget in your project. right?

Comment: yes. i installed it from nuget manager.

Comment: Please try my above suggestions? also, u haven't answered which version of EF u r using?

Comment: Changed your tags. The question has _nothing_ to do with MVC, and everything with EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave the wrong table name over here `[Table("tblUser")]` it should be `[Table("tblEmp")]`. Make sure your column names and datatypes specified in your table(here `tblEmp`) match that of class(here `Employee`) property names and datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to put **`.Schema`** in your ***using***

If you're `table name` is already the same as the name of your `Entity Class` then no need to mapped on it, else then use table mapping

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace MvcDemo.Models
{
    [Table("tblEmployees")] //Exact name of the table should be put in here
    public class Employee
    {
        public int Eid { get; set; }
        public string   Name    { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public int Did { get; set; }
    }
}
```